# Is there any way to intercept all Linq to SQL queries?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, interception

I've built some code that can rebuild expression trees so I can avoid triggering the no supported translation to SQL exception and it works fine as long as I call my function to replace the iqueryable.  The problem is that I'd like it to automatically be applied to all queries in my project without having to worry about calling this function on each one separately.  Is there any way that I can intercept everything?

I've tried using Reflection.Emit to create a wrapping provider and using reflection to replace it on the data context and it turns out that even with Reflection.Emit I can't implement the internal IProvider interface.

I've also tried replacing the provider with a RealProxy based class and that works for non-compiled queries, but the CompiledQuery.Execute method is throwing an exception because it won't cast to the SqlProvider class.  I tried replacing the response to the Compile method on the provider with another proxy so I could intercept the Execute call, but that failed a check on the return type being correct.

I'm open to any other ideas or ways of using what I've already tried?

Comment: Check out DI interception; not all IoC containers support it, you can try with Ninject. I think it does what you want.

Comment: Just had a quick look at Ninject and I'm not really sure how you think it would help?

Comment: Haven't seen your code, but from what I grasped you have a method that you need "wrapped" in another in an automatic way, that's exactly what DI interception can do for you. I'm not posting details from my phone but I'll expand the thought when I get to my computer :)

Comment: I suppose it might be possible to wrap the GetEnumerator call on all IQueryables so that it will generate a new IQueryable and return the Enumerator from that.  I hadn't thought about that approach, but it would need to also do it when .NET methods call the GetEnumerator too and I probably would NOT want it to do it for IQueryables that don't actually have GetEnumerator called - eg. when they themselves are being queried.  I'm not familiar with DI though so I could do with some help on how to go about that

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell whether this is an applicable solution without seeing your code, but if you have a *DI-friendly* app architecture you can implement an *interceptor* and have your favorite IoC container emit the appropriate type for you, at run-time.

Esoteric? A little. Consider an interface like this:

```
public interface ISomeService
{
     IEnumerable<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntities();
     // ...
}
```

This interface might be implemented like this:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
     private readonly DbContext _context // this is a dependency!
     private readonly IQueryTweaker _tweaker; // this is a dependency!

     public SomeService(DbContext context, IQueryTweaker tweaker) // this is constructor injection!
     {
         _context = context;
         _tweaker = tweaker;
     }

     public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntities()
     {
         return _tweaker.TweakTheQuery(_context.SomeEntities).ToList();
     }
}
```

Every time you implement a method of the `ISomeService` interface, there's always a call to `_tweaker.TweakTheQuery()` that wraps the `IQueryable`, and that not only gets boring, it also feels like something is missing a feature - the same feeling you'd get by wrapping every one of these calls inside a `try`/`catch` block, or if you're familiar with MVVM in WPF, by raising this annoying `PropertyChanged` event for every single property setter in your ViewModel.

With DI Interception, you factor this requirement out of your "normal" code and into an "interceptor": you basically tell the IoC container that instead of binding `ISomeService` directly to the `SomeService` implementation, you're going to be decorating it with an *interceptor*, and emit another type, perhaps `SomeInterceptedService` (the name is irrelevant, the actual type only exists at run-time) which "injects" the desired behavior into the desired methods. Simple? Not exactly.

If you haven't designed your code with DI in mind (are your *dependencies* "injected" into your classes' constructor?), it could mean a major refactoring.

The first step breaks your code: remove the `IQueryTweaker` dependency and all the `TweakTheQuery` calls from all `ISomeService` implementations, to make them look like this - notice the `virtual`ness of the method to be intercepted:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
     private readonly DbContext _context

     public SomeService(DbContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }

     public virtual IEnumerable<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntities()
     {
         return _context.SomeEntities.ToList();
     }
}
```

The next step is to configure the IoC container so that it knows to inject the `SomeService` implementation whenever a type's constructor requires an `ISomeService`:

```
_kernel.Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>();
```

At that point you're ready to configure the interception - [if using Ninject this could help](http://codepyre.com/2010/03/using-ninject-extensions-interception-part-1-the-basics/).

But before jumping into that rabbit's hole you should [read this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/06/c-why-decorate-when-you-can-intercept.aspx) which shows how *decorator* and *interceptor* are related.

The key point is, you're not *intercepting* anything that's internal to LINQ to SQL or the .NET framework itself - **you're intercepting your own method calls, wrapping them with your own code**, and with a little bit of help from any decent IoC container, you'll be intercepting the calls to *methods that call upon* Linq to SQL, rather than the direct calls to Linq to SQL itself. Essentially the `IQueryTweaker` dependency becomes a dependency of your interceptor class, and you'll only code its usage once.

An interesting thing about DI interception, is that interceptors can be combined, so you can have a `ExecutionTimerServiceInterceptor` on top of a `AuditServiceInterceptor`, on top of a `CircuitBreakerServiceInterceptor`... and the best part is that you can configure your IoC container so that you can completely forget it exists and, as you add more service classes to the application, all you need to do is follow a naming convention you've defined and *voilà*, you've just written a service that not only accomplishes all the strictly data-related tasks you've just coded, but also a service that will disable itself for 3 minutes if the database server is down, and will remain disabled until it's back up; that service also logs all inserts, updates and deletes, and stores its execution time in a database for performance analysis. The term *[automagical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/automagical)* seems appropriate.

This technique - interception - can be used to address cross-cutting concerns; another way to address those is through AOP, although [some articles](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/05/16/why-choose-di-interception-over-aspect-oriented-programming/) (and Mark Seeman's excellent [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/)) clearly demonstrate how AOP frameworks are a less ideal solution over DI interception.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with DI interception, but I don't *think* this will work.  As far as I understand, the GetSomeEntities call here is something that I'd have to explicitly call, but these queries are being built up as IQuerables backed by internal .NET framework classes in Linq to SQL and then are being executed in most cases by internal .NET code.  I'm not explicitly calling GetSomeEntities - in some cases it may be a method such as ToList or First or Single, but in others I'm looping through the IQueryable with a For Each which implicitly calls GetEnumerator on it.